# Ember + Pyramid Ember Data Request returned a 0 Payload (Empty Content-Type)

Tags: ember.js, pyramid

I need make application with pyramid and emberjs.
I have pyramid view

```
@view_config(route_name='events', request_method='GET', renderer='json')
def events_view(request):
    query = request.dbsession.query(User)
    one = query.filter(User.id).all()
    json_string = json.dumps({"color": "red"})
    return Response(json_string)
```

For develop I need configure ember adapter with local host

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  corsWithCredentials: true,
  host: 'http://127.0.0.1:6543',
  namespace: ''
});
```

and I have this error

```
> Error while processing route: events.index "Ember Data Request
> GET http://127.0.0.1:6543/events returned a 0 Payload (Empty
> Content-Type) "
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow RESTAPI format for response. [refer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_object-root)

Sample format for /event/1

```
{
  "event": {
    "id": 1,
    "color":"red"
  }
}
```

Sample format for /events,

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "color":"red"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "color":"blue"
    }
  ]
}
```